# How can I upload more than one file from a single HTML form in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http, post, file-upload

Internet Explorer (from versions 4 to 7, at least) limits the number of files uploaded using a single 'input type="file"' form field to one. What is the best approach to take if I want to upload more than one file in a single HTTP POST request?

Comment: You can use Java and Flash to get around this limitation - but it has been a major beef with web developers for a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include multiple `input` controls, one per file to be uploaded.

If you don't know how many you want ahead of time, you can use jQuery (or plain javascript) to create them on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [SWFUpload library](http://www.swfupload.org). It allows to select multiple files in the file selection dialog. However, it requires both flash and javascript to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a great resource '[File input (or "upload") in HTML forms](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html)' which discusses cross-browser issues with file upload.